# Jquery on click event not working for simple operation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing a simple jquery click operation and it is not working i don't the reason of why it is happening.

I am seeing the output in the console (I also tried the alert)

here is my code :

```
<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#one").click(function(){
        console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
</script>
<button id='one'>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: use script just before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Please make sure you have import jquery.min.js correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM is not loaded. You should have your jquery events inside the documednt ready function **or** window load function **or** your should use the script just before closing the `</body>` tag as [nullpoiиteя](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1723893/nullpoi%D0%B8te%D1%8F) suggests

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code here
});
```

So, Your code should be

```
<script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
<button id='one'>Click Me</button>
```

Read more about `$( document ).ready()` [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks for the links and answer

Answer (score 0):

This is happen due to event have bind after control are render.
You can try this also:

```
    <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id='one'>Click Me</button>
    <script>
        $("#one").click(function(){
            console.log("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
Document has not fully loaded so the DOM has not found the button.

```
Place your click code inside 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Click event here
});
</script>

<button id='one'>Click Me</button>
```

Case 2:
In other case if you do want to place the code inside "ready" code
just place your button above the click event of the button.

```
<button id='one'>Click Me</button>
<script>
    // Click event here
</script>
```

Case 3:
This is static button, problem can also occur in case of dynamic buttons(buttons you create on runtime).
In that case you can try live click or binding click event.

```
$(document).on("click", "#one", function(){
// Your code here 
});

$("#one").bind("click", function(){
   // Your code here 
});
```